# prompt not showing on terminal

Tags: terminal, java

[image]I installed jdk and somehow modified my path and now my terminal no longer has a prompt, it just says "Last login: Wed Jul 14 15:28:10 on console"

I created another user on my mac and that one has the correct prompt on the terminal.  but i need to know how to fix it on my original user .

is there a way i can modify my user when im logged in as the other user in order to fix this ?

Comment: What shell are you using and what startup files have you got?

Comment: i tried terminal and iterm . i get the same results.  where do i find the startup files?

Comment: The shell is what is run by item and terminal. As for startup files they differ for exch set. A general comment would be if you are trying to use shell - you need to read a tutorial on at least startup files and environment variables. Also when provideing information please cut and paste text not images so that we can read them.

Comment: From the image you are using bash. The startupfiles are given here https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files The file executed as a login shell which terminal does should be ~/.bash_profile however if that does not exist it will read ~/.profile  What is in those files in both your normal user and your new user?

Comment: the problem is that it was working perfectly before i installed jdk and modified my profile somehow.  now that i cannot use the terminal i dont know how to restore it to how it was before

Comment: how can i get to see what ~/.profile says if my terminal doenst work? i cant see that file with finder.

Comment: Which is why I have asked for the contents of those two files - I can guess what has happened (the jdk installer overwrote a file)

Comment: yes i think so but without the terminal prompt i dont know how to open that file

Comment: Find it in Finder and click on it to open in TextEdit - You will probably need to press Cmd-Shift-g to enter the file name as it will be hidden

Comment: Have you try a break (ctrl + c) in this terminal?

Answer (score 1):

i used Ctrl, Shift . to see my hidden files and deleted my .bash_profile file which had some java things in there that i had put by mistake and now its fixed

Comment: Better to move you ~/.profile to ~/.bash_profile then when programs update you profile they don't stop your changes from being run